# How should I configure AWS with credentials?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

Read the amazon docs, still can't get it right. I have my credenials as in `.env` file and want to load them (using a custom function called `config`)

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const credentials = {
  accessKeyId: config('AWSS3AccessKeyID'),
  secretAcccessKey: config('AWSS3SecretAccessKey'),
};

AWS.Config.credentials({ ...credentials });

const S3 = new AWS.S3({
    computeChecksums: false,
});
export default { S3 };
```

It says that `Condif.credetials` is not a function. 
How to properly pass the credentials to `AWS`?
Bonus: Where to pass the bucket name/ region for `AWS S3`?

Answer (score 2):

Look at this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html

```
// Load the SDK for JavaScript
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Load credentials and set region from JSON file
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');

// Create S3 service object
s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

// Call S3 to list current buckets
s3.listBuckets(function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
   } else {
      console.log("Bucket List", data.Buckets);
   }
});
```

Very clearly example. More example from this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-examples.html but I think you should read aws aws-sdk document.

Comment: I will upvote, but I didn't want to load them from path, and there is a problem with env variables. Posting question about this right now.